# Text inside list elements with flex: 1 gets moved to a new line, any way to avoid that?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Because some of the words are too long, they get moved to a new line. If I decrease the font-size, the font becomes too small. I could target the elements with longer words and give them flex: 2 but then I lose the symmetry.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.navigation {
    height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
}
.navUl {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
.navUl li {
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class='navUl'>
            <li>HOME</li>
            <li>ÜBER UNS</li>
            <li>UNSERE LEISTUNGEN</li>
            <li>PREISZUSAMMENSETZUNG</li>
            <li>NÜTZLICHES</li>
            <li>GALERIE</li>
            <li>VIDEOS</li>
            <li>BAUMSCHUTZGESETZ</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `white-space:nowrap` maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, the size  limit on .wrapper(960px) is too small to fit all your list one one line. 
You can use `white-space:nowrap` but this will not keep symmetry and the list will overflow the wrapper.

The best option would be to modify the .wrapper to give it more width (around 1500px should do it), or live with the fact your items break on two lines.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.navigation {
    height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
}
.navUl {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
.navUl li {
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class='navUl'>
            <li>HOME</li>
            <li>ÜBER UNS</li>
            <li>UNSERE LEISTUNGEN</li>
            <li>PREISZUSAMMENSETZUNG</li>
            <li>NÜTZLICHES</li>
            <li>GALERIE</li>
            <li>VIDEOS</li>
            <li>BAUMSCHUTZGESETZ</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```